# Cambios hechos directamente en la bd no se ven en el front

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, trigger

Tengo una web app con angular en el front y java en el back, la base de datos con mySQL, la cosa es que al meter un registro en una tabla, un trigger actualiza el campo de otra, es un campo booleano.

Me explico, al insertar un dato en la tabla este toma un id de otra en un select, así que lo que hace es modificar el item de la otra tabla y ponerlo como no disponible de modo que nadie mas pueda seleccionar ese id de item.

Hasta allí normal, lo que pasa es que el cambio en la tabla que fue modificada con el trigger no se ve reflejada en la vista si no hasta que vuelvo a correr el backend, osea si yo hago un cambio directamente en la base de datos o hago inserts desde consola estos cambios no se ven en el front, entonces me toca volver a correr el back y si se ven los cambios...

¿Existe alguna forma de que los cambios se vean al momento de cambiarlos en la bd o esto es algo que solo pasa en desarrollo? ¿al momento de subirlo a producción no pasaría eso?

Comment: Tú front end se comunica con la base de datos por medio de servicios expuestos en tú back end, por lo tanto modificaciones o inserciones realizadas por consola o directamente a la base de datos no pueden ser detectadas por ésta. Únicamente volviendo a llamar al servicio y que éste retorne los datos nuevos.

Comment: entonces no me sirven los triggers.....

Comment: ¿de que otra forma podría hacer  para que me cambie el estado del item, al hacer post en la otra tabla?.

Comment: En el succes de tú petición http podes modificar el estado de tú scope.